# Free Body Diagram Errors

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque, free-body-diagram

Click to zoom picture:

[image]

Why is the force acting down on the hand only $\vec{F_g}$ ?

Shouldn't it be $\vec{F_g} + \vec{N}_{object, hand}$ ?

Since there is a normal force acting down on the hand from the object, which is equal to the object's gravitational force.

Or is it designating the object and the hand as one thing and $\vec{F_g}$ is the total gravitational force of both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forces acting on the **object** are:

- $\vec F_{\rm g}$ - the gravitational attraction due to the Earth acting downwards
- $\vec N_{\rm hand, object}$ - the normal reaction due to the hand acting upwards

These two forces are of equal magnitude.

The Newton third law pair to $\vec N_{\rm hand, object}$ is $\vec N_{\rm object, hand }$ acting downwards and this is the force which is (misleadingly but economically) labelled $\vec F_{\rm g}$ in the diagram because $\vec F_{\rm g}$ is in the same direction and has the same magnitude as $\vec N_{\rm object,hand}$.

Comment: Read the question carefully. He asks "Why is the force acting down on the **hand** only Fg→ ?" Whereas you answered "The forces acting on the **object** are:" Note that the forces acting on object and hand are different.

Comment: @TheMathemagician After referring to the two forces on the object I then have used the OP's convention for labelling the forces to write about the forces on the hand.

Answer (score 1):

I must respectfully disagree with the posted answer by Farcher.  The first key to a good FBD is clarity on what is being isolated.  In the given diagram, the given system consists of a segment of an arm+hand, including a box held by the hand.  Then, only forces and moments external to this subsystem should be drawn.  Internal contact forces between objects shown attached should not be drawn.  Weight (force due to gravity), for all practical engineering purposes, is always considered external, and can be drawn - either as a single force at the center of mass of the system, or in parts according to how it is distributed, either continuously or discretely, as appropriate.

In the given system of the arm+hand+box, a force "Fg" is drawn through the center of the box, indicating the intent to show the weight of the box and neglect the weight of the arm and hand.  This is a common assumption, and should be considered acceptable, although probably, the weight of the arm is appreciable compared with the weight of a hand-held object.

However, because the box and hand are not separated from each other, even though it is true that there is an action-reaction pair of normal forces of interaction between them, they should not be drawn because they are as yet internal.  The given figure is correct in this regard, but the commentary is at a minimum unclear about this.

Next, the comment that "these two forces are of equal magnitude" is true in static situations, but it is not generally true in dynamic situations.  That is why a best practice of drawing FBDs of the subsystems - here the box and the arm+hand separately - would be to draw normal forces of contact as if they are distinct from the weight of the contacting body.  In general, for a given body, only its own weight should be drawn.  The weight of another body should NEVER be drawn on a given body.

The actual errors with the given FBD are as follows.  First, the diagonal force labelled "F" should not be drawn.  It is presumably representing a force that the muscle applies to the bone, but since these objects are not yet separated, these forces remain internal and invisible.  On the other hand, the FBD lacks reactions that the shoulder applies to the right end of the system.  These might be quite complicated in real biomechanics problems, but can be acceptably represented here by two forces and a moment.

Unfortunately, these kinds of errors and misconceptions abound in physics and engineering textbooks, online tutorials, and elsewhere.  The community of educators must clarify and enforce the best practices of drawing FBDs.  It should be appreciated that these practices are akin to learning a new language, and while clear and precise explanations are necessary, there will be no substitute for formative and supportive teaching and learning environments in which students are given ample time to experiment, get feedback, and try again multiple times.